# laravel passport api role based authorization

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I'm creating laravel api and I'm using Laravel Passport. It is awesome API (but for big apps). I want to use this api for the internal use I mean to creation the android app or such type of own products. **I want to authorize my users based on the role**. So I can create the user `Admin`, `Customer`, `Accountant` so give them only few rights to perform. I have searched and read that **Laravel Passport is used to authorize the third party apps**? not role based authorization? How I can perform role based authorization? **I have read about Laravel Gates and Policies**, but I want to confirm that laravel passport is not providing any role based authorization?

Comment: You can use Passport Scopes? learn about laravel passport scopes or scope based tokens.
https://laravel-news.com/passport-grant-types

Comment: @SalmanZafar I have read but there is to create the client, so how I can create the clients for each user?